# Smartcast and range indicators for certain skills?

Tags: league-of-legends

As far as i know you can have your skills cast when you hit (keydown) your skill key QWER or after you press the target with your mouse. The whole clicking with the mouse to activate the skill sucks - it add too much delay and opportunaty for failure. Using smartcast to activate the skill right away can be very tricky though - especially when aiming long skillshots. Luckily there is an alternative, enabling range indicators. With this enabled, you will see a range indicator when you press keydown and have the skill activate on skill up (with the option to cancle out by clicking with the mouse). All is great, except how can you enable range indicators for certain skills only?

Take Thresh for example. I really  like the range indicator for his Q so i can see where the hook will fly, also i like it on his flay as well (because i always forget to position it correctly when i want to flay towards me - i place it in front of me and then do a 180 degree rotate around myself - yeah i know i need to fix that). His lantern and box though, i don't want to have it delayed till i lift my finger from the keyboard. I want them activated immediately when i hit the key.

I know the UI is not giving me the option to do it individually (yes i can turn off smartcast but that will only make it worse - forcing me to click with the mouse to activate) but is it possible with keybindings somehow? Perhaps edit direcly in the keybindings.ini file?

**This is NOT about enabling smartcast on certain skills. It's enable/disable range indicators for certain skills while using smartcast on ALL skills.**

Can anyone help?

Comment: Excellent question, sad to see that it's not possible. However, I'd like to note that unless you are a very high level player, that 0.1 second is not gonna win or lose you a game. I can see how it matters in LCS matches, but in solo queue it hardly makes a difference (some people play in diamond I with a ping higher than that).

Comment: I'm not a high level player but i got really low ping (which is nice) and it really does make a difference. Not sure if it's me not capable of lifting my fingers fast enough when playing or if the client/controls are somehow buggy. It means a big difference in the heat of battle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm nearly sure this can't be done, I'm sorry. Anyway, I can offer you an alternative: set QWER to smartcast and shift+QWER to non-smartcast. When you'll learn with this, it's absolutely intuitive to use, and it ensures that when precision matters, you place that Anivia's wall perfectly, and when speed matters, you will be fast as lightning is.

Sadly, I don't think there are other alternatives. It's good to learn to play with some spells being smartcasted and some just generally not, and to set your casts every single game for every single champ.

Btw. pro tip: always smartcast on Udyr. It's hard to master, but it really works.

Comment: Turning off smartcast is not really an option for me. It just doesn't work well. It is too slow... I'm stuck between having some skills slowed by normal cast or some skills slowed by range indicators. I think i'll still pick "slowed by range indicators".

Comment: Sometimes you need that precision though. Really recommending to learn shift+skills, as you can choose speed/precision with that.

Comment: I think you're right. I should probably not use range indicators but with smartcast as default. Setting Shift+skill to non-smart and then use that for precision - or re configuring based on champ

Comment: Really good idea, I will try to use this !

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible.**

Ether you use smartcast and fire the ability on key down and you don't have range indicators

or

you use smartcast with range indicators and fire the ability on key up.

but why do you want range indicators when firing a skill on keydown? When you really want to fire a skillshot immediately you don't lose that much time (< 50ms) when they a fired on key up.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me but i really feel it matters - the extra time it takes me to raise my finger. I suspect either myself of lingering on the key or the client somehow being buggy when i have it on. Also i read somewhere that smartcast will fire the moment you get out of CC - not sure it works with smartcast as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do as you say here without editing the game files themselves (there might be consequences for doing so). But there's a input file in `*\League of Legends\Config\input.ini` which you can edit without problems.
[Here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hotkeys_and_commands) you can read about all of the hotkeys and commands for League of Legends. But there's no known commands for enabling/disabling the range indicator for specific skills in this file.

Comment: Yeah as mentioned in my question i was thinking if it was possible to edit that file but i can't see an option for it there either...